# Suggested Way to Implement Google Cloud Messaging in my Android App

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to push updates from my node.js API to my android app. I'd like to find the easiest acceptable way to do it.

The GCM Client Helper library looks easy but appears to be deprecated. Is it a really bad idea to use it?

The suggested [replacement](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) seems significantly more complicated. Is there a way around this complication?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As with any deprecated solution, it could stop working at any time and you'd be forced to rewrite your application to move to the non-deprecated solution. In this case, THe GCM Client Helper library has been deprecated for **almost 2 years** and I would not consider it for any new projects at this point, particularly since it is tied to [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps), which, per the [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms), is no longer required to work at all after April 20, 2015.

Given that, I would **strongly** recommend using the Google Play Services GCM API. Note that the replacement training you linked is a very full featured, detailed form. You may find the documentation on [GoogleCloudMessaging](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) to be a more minimal example of what is needed (frankly, not any more than the old model).